# "Index file corrupt" usando git

Tags: git

Uso `git` para control de versiones.

Pero he empezado a recibir el siguiente mensaje de error cuando intento hacer cualquier operación en el repositorio:

> ```
> fatal: index file corrupt
> ```

Esto hace que no pueda operar ni hacer nada con el código.

¿Por qué ocurre ese error? ¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

Comment: Aunque la [respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52724/index-file-corrupt-usando-git/52725#52725) de @ArieCwHat es correcta, yo que tu, haría un backup de dicho archivo ya que en este archivo es el "**staging area for commits**" y uno nunca sabe que pueda pasar

Comment: @Jorius Gracias por la recomendación. La tendré en cuenta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Buenas.

Esto podría ocurrir cuando algunos archivos de la carpeta `.git`, específicamente el `index` se daña.

para arreglarlo intenta (en linux):

```
rm -f .git/index
git reset --keep
```

### Explicación

Para reproducir el error:

```
arie@dev:/var/www/repo$ ls -lha .git/               # Ver los archivos de .git/
[... otros archivos ...]
-rw-r--r--   1 arie arie  175K mar  2 13:18 index   # Fichero correcto

arie@dev:/var/www/repo$ git add .                   # Este funciona!
arie@dev:/var/www/repo$ truncate -s 1000 .git/index # Echamos a perder :(
arie@dev:/var/www/repo$ git add .                   # Error!
error: bad index file sha1 signature
fatal: index file corrupt
```

#### El fichero Index

> The staging area is a file, generally contained in your Git directory, that stores information about what will go into your next commit. It’s sometimes referred to as the “index”, but it’s also common to refer to it as the staging area. [The Three States - Git Basics](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics)

El "index", "stagging area" o "área de preparación" es un fichero que contiene la captura del árbol de trabajo actual que será incluida en el siguiente "commit".

[image: Imagen 1]

#### El comando git reset [<mode>] [<commit>]

> This form resets the current branch head to <commit> and possibly updates the index (resetting it to the tree of <commit>) and the working tree depending on <mode>. [Git reset - Documentación git](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#git-reset-emgitresetemltmodegtltcommitgt)

Git reset reubica el puntero "head" al commit seleccionado entre `< >`, junto con esto actualiza el fichero "index". Si no se provee el paramatro `<commit>`, por defecto es `HEAD`. Para `<mode>` es `--mixed`.

#### opción *--keep*

> Resets index entries and updates files in the working tree that are different between <commit> and HEAD. If a file that is different between <commit> and HEAD has local changes, reset is aborted. [Opción --keep - Documentación Git](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#git-reset---keep)

Puedes leer este [articulo en el blog de git-scm](https://git-scm.com/blog/2011/07/11/reset.html)(en Ingles) para tener mucha mas información.

Comment: Si `.git/index` es una carpeta y/o directorio, ¿no deberías agregar la opción `-r` junto a `-f` para que quede `rm -rf` y se pueda eliminar la carpeta de forma recursiva?

Comment: Oh. me he expresado mal, .git es el directorio, index es un fichero :(